# FPDF - Negrito apenas uma parte da string no MultiCell

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf

O meu problema é o seguinte, eu estou a fazer um certificado em FPDF, e existe partes de strings que têm de ficar em negrito por ex:

CODE:

```
$nome="Marco";
$string1="Certifica-se que ".$nome;
$pdf->Cell('160','8',$string1,0,1,'L',false);
```

O resultado o output seria:

> Certifica-se que Marco

O que eu pretendo é :

> Certifica-se que  **Marco**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ao invés de usar Cell, por que não usar writeHTML com posições?

```
   $pdf->SetY($pos_Y);
   $pdf->SetX($pos_X);
   $pdf->writeHTML('Certifica-se que <b>MARCO</b>');
```